# What is the meaning of this "って" in this reply

Tags: sentence-final-particles

[The source is in here](http://i.redwh.al/sf.jpg)

Q:サルと一緒にするなって感じ？

A:やっぱり癒されたいって気持ちは動物も一緒なのかな**って**…

I cannot figure out the meaning of "って" in the end of the sentence.

According to the dictionary, "って" has two meanings when acting as a 終助詞:

(1)ほかからの話を紹介する｡ということだ｡

(2)相手の言葉をとらえて,反問する

But they do not seem to fit the dialog above.

By the way, can I rephrase the question as "サルと一緒にするなという感じ？"

Answer (score 4):

> Q:サルと一緒{いっしょ}にするなって感{かん}じ？
>
> A:やっぱり癒{いや}されたいって気持{きも}ちは動物{どうぶつ}も一緒なのかな**って**…

The 「って」 used at the end of the answer is the **informal version of the quotative 「と」**.

A verb phrase such as 「思{おも}います」、「思っちゃいます」、「（いう）気{き}がする」、「（いう）気がしちゃいます」, etc. is left unuttered following the 「って」.

This is a very common phenomenon in informal speech as using a verb like 「思う」 could make a statement too direct/assertive for the Japanese taste.

> By the way, can I rephrase the question as "サルと一緒にするなという感じ？"

Yes, you can.

You may have noticed that a verb phrase is left unuttered in the question as well.  It ends with the noun 「感じ」 instead of a "full" verb phrase like 「感じがしません**か**」.