# What is the meaning of the "な" in this question?

Tags: meaning

[Dialog in hear](http://i.redwh.al/sf.jpg), [Followed by this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57895/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-in-this-reply/57897#57897)

Q:サルと一緒にする**な**って感じ？

A:やっぱり癒されたいって気持ちは動物も一緒なのかなって…

What is the meaning of this bolded "な" in the interrogative sentence? Is it an interjectional particle that softens the "語勢" or means "禁止".

I am not totally understand the meaning of the question, truth to be told. Does the questioner intended to ask "How is the feeling of having hot spring with monkeys?" or "Do you find it unpleasant to have hot spring with monkeys?"

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to user "Chocolate" who pointed out a mistake in my original answer.

「AをBと一緒にする」 means "to mix/confuse/include A with B"

saru to issho ni suruNA tte kanji? First, the person or people being asked this question are not knowable from the context... could be someone just thinking aloud, or asking one or more people... but essentially it's "You mean, 'don't lump me in with monkeys'?"

"suruna" is a very strongly (or crudely) worded negative command: "DON'T do it!" you see this pattern attached to other root verbs as well. "hanasuna!" "Don't talk!" "taberuna!" "Don't eat it!"

and "tte kanji" is a question ending that implies the the person asking the question is trying to 'get a sense' of some meaning, and is asking for verification of their understanding. So although the word "kanji" does mean "feeling/sense", the phrase 'tte kanji' is never asking about how someone feels, but what they mean.

Comment: 「サルと一緒にするな！」は "Don't do it with monkeys" って意味じゃないですけど・・・。 「AをＢと一緒にする」"mix/confuse A with B" (ところで「一緒」は isshou じゃなくて issho って読みます)

Comment: OH!  I totally forgot about that form!! You're right! I will edit the answer. *head slap*